# Noisy blur using compositing nodes

Tags: node-editor, blur

I want to make a noisy blurred emitting object using compositing nodes.

Similar effect which you could see looking through waving water.

[image]

Comment: Did you try mixing two blur nodes outputs with noise textures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to get an effect like this is by using a noise texture to vary the *Size* input of a blur node. Note that *Variable Size* must be enabled:

[image]

By mixing different sizes and types of noise textures, and perhaps throwing in a bit of displacement, you can control the effect to get any sort of look you want. For example:

[image]